# How to open this program?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I need open this application-->
[Decision tree](https://github.com/saebyn/java-decision-tree)

I have used netbeans and it has not worked, so I have installed eclipse and it seems that the file recognizes me.

What I do is import that application from Github, until there everything perfect, the problem is that when I give it to run, it does not work.

One problem I get is the following:

> Buildfile: C:\Users\user1\workspace\Arbolito\java-decision-tree-master\build.xml
>   compile:
>       [javac] Compiling 9 source files to C:\Users\user1\workspace\Arbolito\java-decision-tree-master\build\classes
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Users\user1\workspace\Arbolito\java-decision-tree-master\build.xml:19:
>   C:\Users\user1\workspace\Arbolito\java-decision-tree-master\lib
>   does not exist.
>
> Total time: 550 milliseconds

I put the line of code in the XML file that gives me the problem

```
 <target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false" debug="on" />
  </target>
```

Does anyone know how to run the program?

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  You are trying to reference a folder (\lib) that does not exist.  Did you edit the ant build file, and ensure that all properties ($...) are set to valid values ?

Comment: I have not edited the build file, just import Github to eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Create a lib folder in your project and include SL4J and Junit jar  in that folder.

Comment: When he uses eclipse, there is no need to have a local copy of the JUnit jar methinks. He just needs to enable it in the build path libraries (?)

Comment: yes you are right but he need both junit and SLF4J in his build path